# Custom function to autofill the data in zoho crm across modules

Tags: zoho

I've two custom modules say `A` and `B`.

`A` module has some fields and `B` has some fields. Now  I want to populate the fields from `B` module to `A` module which are common in both using a lookup field in my `A` module.

I've tried [this](https://help.zoho.com/portal/en/community/topic/auto-fill-fields-with-data-from-a-different-module) . But this is only for default modules and not custom modules.

I want to write a function for a single case.
`B` module has a text field with label called `b` and `A` module also have a text field with label called `b`. I want to populate the text field value of `A` module with that of `B` module.

Answer (score 0):

it's the same for all modules. case:1 IF you have One record for the custom module, you need to pass the API Name of that module. eg: CSATDetails = zoho.crm.getRecordById("CSAT",ccsat_id); CSAT=Custome module: find the API name of that Module. --> Setting--> API-->API Names-->Right side API Name ie Link Name. case:2 IF you have many records https://www.zoho.com/deluge/help/crm/get-related-records.html CSATDetails = zoho.crm.getRelatedRecords("relationName","ParentModule",ccsat_id);

Comment: ` zoho.crm.getRecordById("CSAT",ccsat_id)` what's `ccsat_id` how to know this?

Comment: ccsat_id- its unique record id provided by Zoho. whenever you click on any records on URL you will see that.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly You need to capture the ID for Form A which should be present in the lookup field in Form B, You can do this by using zoho.crm.getRecordByID() function.
After which you must create a map having the key value pair of api names of the fields and their appropriate values.
You need to pass the above mentioned map variable in zoho.crm.updateRecord() function call and that is all you need to do.